# Migrate from premium (Classic SQL DB) to Serverless

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

My Azure database is on Premium(Classic database), Usually, I put it on P1(125 DTUs) but on the peak time I keep it on P4(500 DTUs), which is a very cumbersome task to change every time. I have following questions:

1. What will be best migration service to migrate.
2. If I go with Serverless (General purpose) then would it be cost effective and on what basis I need to choose vCore(.5,1,2 etc.), memory, IO.

please help me in this.

Comment: Hi @Naval Singh, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.What will be best migration service to migrate?

Azure SQL database only support manual dynamic scalability, but not autoscale. The easiest way to migrate the service tier is setting on Portal. You also could run the command with Powershell: https://dataplatformlabs.com/change-azure-sql-database-pricing-tier/. There isn't a best migration service to migrate.

2.If I go with Serverless (General purpose) then would it be cost effective and on what basis I need to choose vCore(.5,1,2 etc.), memory, IO..

It depends on the max DTU resource you will use. Then you can get suitable Vcore resource by calculation. Ref this turorial: [Migrate Azure SQL Database from the DTU-based model to the vCore-based model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-dtu-to-vcore).